# Find and replace "return whatever;" to "return whatever.Value;"

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I wish to find all "return whatever;" with "return whatever.Value;".

Is this possible in Visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

```
return ([^;]+); # find
return \1.Value; # replace
```

Make sure you select `Regular expressions` in the search options.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Ctl-Shift-F or Ctl-Shift-H, you'll open the Find/Replace dialogbox. There you should be able to find all the whatevers and change them to whatever.Value

Comment: Problem is that I wish to match "whatever" as regex. That is, whatever can be anything.